# My XPS 15 gets too hot when it is connected to adapter as it runs

Tags: dell, overheating, xps, adapter

When I connect my XPS 15 to adapter for the first time while it is running, all the area next to the adapter plug gets too hot in a short time. If I restart the computer, then slowly it gets normal. Do you have any idea about this problem?